# Push notification in flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

Guy's i'm building mobile application with flash builder using flex so while reading about the push notification I've stopped on 
 [this  link](HTTP://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/notification.html)
Lately Google deprecated Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) and C2DM will accept no new users.C2DM developers are strongly encouraged to move to Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). GCM is the next generation of C2DM.

Finally how to use **AIR native extension to push notifications with GCM**

Comment: Which Native Extension are you using?  If the underlying Android APIs have changed; most likely you'll have to create a new native extension related to those new APIs.

Answer (score 2):

The native extension you pointed to is not for Push Notifications.  Looking at the code for the sample project, the needed steps for Push Notifications are not present.  I believe it's for triggering notification behavior on the device from within your app.

A device has to register for notifications from it's parent/native platform's service (GCM/C2DM on Android & ANPs on Apple), then set up methods to handle incoming notifications.

The native extensions you are/were looking for are:
[Piotr Walczyszyn's As3C2DM ANE for Android](http://www.riaspace.com/2011/09/as3c2dm-air-native-extension-to-push-notifications-with-c2dm/)
and
[Piotr Koscierzynski's APNs ANE for iThings](http://flashsimulations.com/2011/12/16/apple-push-notification-service-native-extension-for-adobe-air/)

The first won't do you any good anymore, because, as you mentioned, you can't register an app to use C2DM anymore.

The haven't tried using the second one because I don't have an Apple license yet, but based on the comments I've read, it seems that he released this ANE as a demo & it's not really made for people to use.  He doesn't want to release that version for business reasons or whatever.

While searching, you may find [this Adobe Forums post for an APNs ANE](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/940310), but he won't share the extension anymore. So don't bother asking him.

The last resources I can point you to are:
If you want to use Piotr Koscierzynski's APNs extension,
[you may need this help building on a PC](http://www.riaxe.com/blog/uncategorized/apn-using-flex-mobile-in-windows-native-extensions/).

This is a really nice 
[suite of extensions for $100](http://labs.distriqt.com/native-extensions) (note that it supports *C2DM*, not GCM, as of July 4, 2012)

And this is *just* an [APNs extension for $25](http://codecanyon.net/item/advance-ios-apns/168673)

So, that's everything that I know / remember that I can share.  I'll try to update this if I find any other options worth mentioning.  I've already built me app more than 60%, but I basically have to start over now, so ... =/

I'd write them myself, but I don't know Java or Objective-C
=b

Best of luck to everyone who reads this cuz they're in the same boat.
=)
Todd

Comment: +1 from me. Very good summary of the current push notifications for air options!

Comment: Just a note: The package at http://labs.distriqt.com/native-extensions is a complete GCM solution, not C2DM as stated. Supports both APNS and GCM with a single cross platform ANE.

Answer (score 1):

distriqt have upgrade their ANE  to support GCM :
http://labs.distriqt.com/native-extensions#pushnotifications

To complete the List:
https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification